# Dynamic content loading using custom element vs dynamic component in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-components, custom-element

What is the difference between loading dynamic content in angular using new [custom elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) in angular 6  and [Component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: I think one difference is when we generate a component on the fly, using dynamic component we can resolve that component and add it to Dom with change detectors while custom element cannot load newly on-the-fly-generated components

Comment: and also,  dynamic component needs a template `<div #templateName> </div>` in html file to be placed there, but custom element doesn't need any templates